# Cancelling of TimePickerFragment

Tags: android, dialog, datetimepicker

I am using `TimePickerFragment` to get the value from the time picker.I created a transparent activity and its code in the `onCreate()` method is

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

    newFragment.setCancelable(true);
```

The TimePickerFragment() class is as follow:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

              final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = minute;
            Date date = new Date();
            date.setHours(hour);
            date.setMinutes(minute);

            // updateTime(hour, minute);

            Adapter.Time = date;

            this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDismiss(dialog);

        }

        @Override
        public void dismiss() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

The Problem is that I made this dialog `Cancelable(true)`which is working fine. But When I cancel the dialog or click on the Done button, it execute the `onTimeSet(...)` method and values of date is filled up which should not be filled up in case of cancelling the dialog. So, I want to get the event when user click on the Done button and only then the values to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid this could be to set a *boolean* variable to true when you click done button and check whether it is true inside your onTimeSet function. Do the following things also:

when declaring the boolean variable, set it as **false**.

If done button is clicked, set it as **true**;

in onTimeset, **if** the boolean variable is true and you actually do set the time, set the boolean variable back to **false**.

This way, *none* of these onTimeSet() operations will happen if you cancel it, only if you click done, it will occur.

EDIT: To use on click event of done, modify your oncreate dialog using this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(MainActivity.message)
    .setTitle("Put any title")
           .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                      hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                       minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                     return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                false);


               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//do nothing here


 }
    });
```

I think my edit would eliminate the requirement of the bool variable too.

Edit 2:

Or since you are extending from dialog fragment, try defining an implementation of the onCreateDialog for Dialogfragment where you set the bool variable for your super class(which is the dialogfragment) and call it from your implementation of onCreatedDialog before your operations. This way it might work.

Comment: But I can't even get the click event of Done Button.

Comment: How are you setting the positive and negative case Done and cancel buttons in the dialog. Please add that code too :)

Comment: Yeah, this may be useful if I had used simple timePicker but I used the TimePickerFragment and if you see the class it implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener which has its own method to show the dialog.

Comment: Try to see where the execution proceeds to when you click done, and when you click cancel, using print statements. Then use the bool variable approach accordingly.

Comment: Or since you are extending from dialog fragment, try defining an implementation of the onCreateDialog for Dialogfragment where you set the bool variable for your super class(which is the dialogfragment) and call  it from your implementation of onCreatedDialog *before* your operations. This way it might work